# Swift 2.1: CAGradientLayer color location & distribution

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, cagradientlayer

My need is to show 3-colored distribution in a view. So I'm using following code.

```
func drawWithGradientLayer() {

        // total contains sum of all values contained in segmentValues variable.
        // I'm using green -> Orange -> Red colors as colors

        if total == 0 {
            return
        }

        if gradientLayer.superlayer != nil {
            gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

        var previous: CGFloat = (CGFloat(segmentValues[0])/CGFloat(total))
        var locations: [NSNumber] = [previous]

        for var i=1; i<segmentValues.count; i++ {
            previous = previous + (CGFloat(segmentValues[i])/CGFloat(total))
            locations.append(previous)
        }

        locations.append(1.0) // Line may need to be commented

        gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)

        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.locations = locations

        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
}
```

But problem is that gradient colors are not distributed according to my requirements. E.g if ihave values of [1,0,1] so bar should display 50% red & 0% orange and 50% red. If values are [0,0,1] then only redColor should be drawn. How can I achieve this without grid lines?
[image]

any other better solution will always be appreciated :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key here is to understand how `locations` in CAGradientLayer work:

> The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1. The values must be monotonically increasing.

So you cannot specify locations like `[1, 0, 1]`, but should rather use something like `[0.0, 0.33, 0.67, 1.0]`, and the number of location values **must** be the same as your `colors` count.

To make a gradient with short color transitions like in your images, you have to repeat each color twice and specify the appropriate locations:
[image: gradients]

So your code should be something like:

```
    gradientLayer.colors =  [
        UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,  UIColor.greenColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor, UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor,
        UIColor.redColor().CGColor,    UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    ]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0]
```

If you want to get a 2-color gradient while not changing its colors, you can set a value less than 0 for `startPoint.x` or greater than 1 for `endPoint.x`, and set multiple locations to zero, e.g.:

```
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: -0.01, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0]
```

which would give a result similar to this:

[image: 2-color gradient]

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we do same for arc or cricle ? Thanks

Comment: @Chetan it is impossible to draw a circular gradient using CAGradientLayer, it has to be drawn manually using CGContextDrawRadialGradient. Alternatively, you can use a ready-made view like this one - https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKGradientView

Comment: Good explanation!